# Rest API to create/update data extract activity is not working

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, rest, ssjs, data-extract

Could someone please point out the mistake in the below script?

```javascript
var restapi_url = "https://XXXXX.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/automation/v1/dataextracts";

var restapi_payload = '{"name": "Test DE extract","key": "966D6D48-1AA4-4812-ABD6-7A2DC5B751D5","description": "Trying Update","dataExtractTypeId": "bb94a04d-9632-4623-be47-daabc3f588a6","fileSpec": "TestingUpdateActivity.csv","intervalType": 0,"dataFields": [{"name": "ColumnDelimiter","type": "string","value": ","},{"name": "DECustomerKey","type": "string","value": "6F29911C-2741-43B9-BC35-26D5CFBC7F74"},{"name": "HasColumnHeaders","type": "bool","value": "True"},{ "name": "TextQualified", "type": "bool","value": "True"},{"name": "UsesLineFeed","type": "bool","value": "False"}]}';

var headerNames = ["Authorization"]; 
var s1="Bearer ";
var headerValues = "Bearer " + accessToken;

var req = new Script.Util.HttpRequest(restapi_url);
req.contentType = "application/json"
req.setHeader("Authorization", headerValues);
req.method = "POST"; 
req.postData = restapi_payload;
var restapi_result = req.send();
```

I am getting Bad Request (400) error.

Create automation soap api

```xml
</s:Header>
<s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <CreateRequest xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
            <Objects xsi:type="Automation">
                <Name>System Data Views5</Name>
                <CustomerKey>DataViews_Automation5</CustomerKey>
                <AutomationTasks>
                    <AutomationTask>
                        <Name>Test DE extract8</Name>
                        <Activities>
                            <Activity>
                                <ObjectID>bb94a04d-9632-4623-be47-daabc3f588a6</ObjectID>
                                <ActivityObject xsi:type="DataExtractActivity">
                                    <ObjectID>bb94a04d-9632-4623-be47-daabc3f588a6</ObjectID>
                                    <CustomerKey>Test DE extract8</CustomerKey>
                                    <Name>Test DE extract5</Name>
                                </ActivityObject>
                            </Activity>
                        </Activities>
                    </AutomationTask>
                </AutomationTasks>
                <AutomationType>scheduled</AutomationType>
            </Objects>
        </CreateRequest>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

It creates the automation but gives the following error:

[image]

Comment: I'd suggest getting it working in Postman first, then implementing it with SSJS.  Postman will also generate the JS code for you -- as a place to start.

Comment: Hi Adam, thank you for the suggestion. I tried with Postman, the status returned was 400. The error message said {"errors":[{"message":"Name already exists"},{"message":"CustomerKey already exists"}]}. I am trying to change the DE customer key of an existing data extract activity in the system. Is there anything that does this? REST/SOAP/SSJS?

Comment: Have you tried a patch instead of a post?

Comment: Thanks a lot! EazyE, that worked.

Answer (score 3):

Exactly as @EazyE commented, you are doing a **POST** which is a 'create' and to update you need to do a **PATCH** which is update. Although the Endpoint is mostly the same, the Method has to be different.

There is also a slight difference in that you need to include the dataextractid inside the URL at the end for the **PATCH** as well as in the JSON in the body.

Making the update call like so:

```
PATCH /automation/v1/dataextracts/{{dataextractid}} 
Host: {{subdomain}}.rest.marketingcloudapis.com
Authorization: Bearer {{authToken}}
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "dataExtractDefinitionId": "xxxxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "name": "myExtract",
    "key": "myExtract",
    "description": "",
    "dataExtractTypeId": "xxxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx",
    "fileSpec": "myFile.zip",
    "intervalType": 0,
    "startDate": "01/01/2014",
    "endDate": "01/30/2014",
    "dataFields": [
        {
            "name": "AccountIDs",
            "type": "string",
            "value": "*"
        },
        {
            "name": "Attributes",
            "type": "string",
            "value": ""
        },
        .... etc.
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Gortonington, that worked!

Comment: Also, when I call the create Automation SOAP , using this data extract activity. The Automation is created successfully but when I open the activity step, it gives me the following error(attached in the initial question)

Comment: @Gortonington how can we do the same thing for file transfer activity?